# Using DateRangePicker in a Blazor libary

Tags: css, components, blazor

When using the component the doc. (https://github.com/jdtcn/BlazorDateRangePicker) says that this

```
<script src="_content/BlazorDateRangePicker/clickAndPositionHandler.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/BlazorDateRangePicker/daterangepicker.min.css" />
```

needs to be added to the app. in the head section.

Now I am using the BlazorDateRangePicker in a Razor component library - MyLibrary.
To use that library in my app. I need to add those to lines to my app referencing them in my library

```
<script src="_content/MyLibrary/BlazorDateRangePicker/clickAndPositionHandler.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/MyLibrary/BlazorDateRangePicker/daterangepicker.min.css" />
```

this does not work - I get 404 when loading the files. I have also tried

_content/MyLibrary/_content/BlazorDateRangePicker

and all other possible combinations.

How is this done ?

Comment: Have you installed the package in your web project?  I just installed as per the instructions and worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused with how Blazor references embedded resources.

The `BlazorDateRangePicker` library's resources would be referenced as per the instructions, e.g.

```html
<script src="_content/BlazorDateRangePicker/clickAndPositionHandler.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/BlazorDateRangePicker/daterangepicker.min.css" />
```

You're importing your own library (`MyLibrary`) that *references* this package, but the reference path doesn't change - it's still the `_content/BlazorDateRangePicker/..` prefix.